# How to code 'timed deletion' in xcode, using Parse's Anywall?

Tags: ios, time, parse-platform, geotagging

I'm new to app dev and Xcode, so I'm using the Anywall app creation tutorial on Parse's website. I finished, but I want to experiment with timed deletion. That meaning, after an arbitrary amount of time has passed (ex. 24 hrs) after a geotag's creation, the geotag will be deleted.

Code is available here -> https://www.parse.com/tutorials/anywall

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it in the app, do it on the server.

Configure a job to run a cloud code service daily which will check the dates on the target objects and delete them.

Comment: Hey Wain, thanks for the tip. So you suggest adding a service to Parse that cleans the target objects out? Could you go into a little more detail?